# AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat not starting the Animation?

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, morphing

I am trying to implement Morphing animation using AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat class. Basically I am trying to achieve animation as Evernote App - note Edit functionality (where user press on Edit button and Back button Morphed to Tick Button).

I have done following in .JAVA file :

```
private AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat arrowDoneAnimatedVectorDrawable;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_compose_note);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    if (null != getSupportActionBar()) {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);          

        arrowDoneAnimatedVectorDrawable = AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat.create(this, R.drawable.animation_vector_consolidated);

       getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(arrowDoneAnimatedVectorDrawable);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    findViewById(R.id.fab_edit_note).setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (arrowDoneAnimatedVectorDrawable.isRunning()) {
        arrowDoneAnimatedVectorDrawable.stop();
    } else {
        arrowDoneAnimatedVectorDrawable.start();
    }
}
```

Below is consolidated .XML to Morph Back button path to tick button :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animated-vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:igonore="NewApi"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_black_24dp">

    <target
        android:animation="@animator/arrow_done_transition"
        android:name="head"/>
</animated-vector>
```

Below .XML file is to run an Animator on button paths :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<objectAnimator
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@integer/morphing_time"
    android:propertyName="pathData"
    android:valueType="pathType"
    android:valueFrom="M 20.0,11.0 H 7.83 l 5.59,-5.59 L 12.0,4.0 l -8.0,8.0 l 8.0,8.0 L 12.0,20.0 L 12.0,20.0 l 1.41,-1.41 L 7.83,13.0 H 20.0 v -2.0 L 20.0,11.0"
    android:valueTo="M 9.0,16.2 H 9.0 l 0.0,0.0 L 4.8,12.0 l 0.0,0.0 l -1.4,1.4 L 9.0,19.0 L 21.0,7.0 l -1.4,-1.4 L 9.0,16.2 H 9.0 v 0.0 L 9.0,16.2"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    />
```

I have used [VectAlign](https://github.com/bonnyfone/vectalign) to align both the icon paths.

And, finally this is how Back button Vector look like :

```
    <vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24.0"
        android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF000000"
        android:pathData="M 20.0,11.0 H 7.83 l 5.59,-5.59 L 12.0,4.0 l -8.0,8.0 l 8.0,8.0 L 12.0,20.0 L 12.0,20.0 l 1.41,-1.41 L 7.83,13.0 H 20.0 v -2.0 L 20.0,11.0"/>
</vector>
```

I have spend around two days to figure out the morphing concept and its implementation but still no luck. Am I missing or doing something wrong here..

Thanks.